# How can I update the favorite icon in the News page after I remove the item in the Favorite page?

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, sorry for my bad English. So my problem is, I have a list of news in the News Page fetch from the api and there is a favorite/heart icon on each list. After I added one of the items in the favorite Page then unfavorited it, returning to the News Page, the previous status of the item still retains.

The question is, **how can I pass the status of the item to the News Page after I unfavorited it to the Favorite Page**?

Note: The Favorite and News Screen shares the NewsList class

```
class DisplayFavorites extends StatefulWidget {
  static List<dynamic> favoriteDataList = [];
  static List<String> favoriteId = [];
  static bool isFavoriteScreenActive = false;
  const DisplayFavorites({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<DisplayFavorites> createState() => _DisplayFavoritesState();
}

class _DisplayFavoritesState extends State<DisplayFavorites> {
  get favDataList => DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NewsList(
      results: favDataList,
      // isFavorite: _isFavorite,
    );
  }
}
```

From the news_list.dart - this is the part where the favorite icon is

```
  final List<bool> _isNewsScreenFavorite = <bool>[];
  @override
  initState() {
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.results.length; i++) {
      _isNewsScreenFavorite.add(false);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

....

child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (DisplayFavorites.isFavoriteScreenActive) {
                              _isNewsScreenFavorite[index] =
                                  !_isNewsScreenFavorite.elementAt(index);
                              DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList
                                  .remove(wResults);
                            } else {
                              _isNewsScreenFavorite[index] =
                                  !_isNewsScreenFavorite.elementAt(index);
                              _isNewsScreenFavorite[index]
                                  ? DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList
                                      .add(wResults)
                                  : DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList
                                      .remove(wResults);
                            }
                            //print(wResults.publishedAt);
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          DisplayFavorites.isFavoriteScreenActive
                              ? Icons.favorite
                              : _isNewsScreenFavorite.elementAt(index)
                                  ? Icons.favorite
                                  : Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 50,
                        ),
```

This is the whole code for news_list.dart (You can check this if you don't understand the code above)

```
class _NewsListState extends State<NewsList> {
  final List<bool> _isNewsScreenFavorite = <bool>[];
  @override
  initState() {
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.results.length; i++) {
      _isNewsScreenFavorite.add(false);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.results.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        var wResults = widget.results.elementAt(index);
        return InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.red,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplaySelectedNews(
                  urlToImage: wResults.urlToImage,
                  author: wResults.author,
                  description: wResults.description,
                  publishedAt: wResults.publishedAt,
                  title: wResults.title,
                  content: wResults.content,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 2,
              horizontal: 10,
            ),
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    child: Image.network(
                      wResults.urlToImage,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 150,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(1),
                      colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        wResults.title.toString().trim(),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.merge(
                              const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 5.0,
                    bottom: 10.0,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (DisplayFavorites.isFavoriteScreenActive) {
                              _isNewsScreenFavorite[index] =
                                  !_isNewsScreenFavorite.elementAt(index);
                              DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList
                                  .remove(wResults);
                            } else {
                              _isNewsScreenFavorite[index] =
                                  !_isNewsScreenFavorite.elementAt(index);
                              _isNewsScreenFavorite[index]
                                  ? DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList
                                      .add(wResults)
                                  : DisplayFavorites.favoriteDataList
                                      .remove(wResults);
                            }
                            //print(wResults.publishedAt);
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          DisplayFavorites.isFavoriteScreenActive
                              ? Icons.favorite
                              : _isNewsScreenFavorite.elementAt(index)
                                  ? Icons.favorite
                                  : Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 50,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use state management such as `BLoc`, `ChangeNotifier`, `ValueNotifier`, ...
Here, we should use `ValueNotifier` because we just need to manage only 1 value.

Firstly, we need to create a `ValueNotifer`:

```
ValueNotifier<bool> isFavoriteListenable = ValueNotifier<bool>(false); //the initial value is false
```

Next, to change that value, we simply use:

```
isFavoriteListenable.value = true;//change the value to true
```

Lastly, to listen to the change made to the `isFavoriteListenable`, we use `ValueListenableBuilder`. Surround the widget that need to change when `isFavorite` value change, just like this:

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: isFavoriteListenable,
  builder: (BuildContext context, bool isFavorite,Widget child){
       return NewsList(
         results: favDataList,
         isFavorite: isFavorite,
);
      }
)
```

If you didn't understand or want more infomation, check this one: [link](https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b#:%7E:text=ValueNotifier%20is%20a%20special%20type,its%20holding%20value%20gets%20change.)